# Why are there only two bits?

Tags: ar.hardware-architecture

I was thinking that why are their only two bits,0&1. I know that they represent a particular switch in IC being opened or closed. But why not for switch neither completely open nor closed i.e. in intermediate stage relaying only a partial amount of voltage. Then we can have more than one bits, which can make coding much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit is, by definition, a ***bi***nary digi***t***, and binary means base 2.

Base two is the most common model of computing, but it is not the only one.  There is also [analog computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer), which is not that interesting to computer science.  [Ternary logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer), on the other hand, does lead to some interesting theory.  In that case, however, each digit would be called a ***trit***.

One advantage of representing numbers in base 3 is that it is more [efficient](//math.stackexchange.com/q/446664/77144), since 3 is closer to *e* ≈ 2.71828….  On the other hand, ternary logic is harder to implement reliably in electronic circuits, so binary computing receives nearly all of the attention.